# When I try to generate Fedex shipping label using magento version 2.2.6. The error is showing "Customs Clearance Detail is required."

Tags: magento2.2.6

If I try to change file Carrier.php  add 'CommercialInvoice' => ['Purpose' => "SOLD"], the error is showing like

[08-Feb-2019 12:20:39 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script in /home/mindbsoul/public_html/staging/vendor/magento/module-fedex/Model/Carrier.php on line 7

But there is no space on this page

kindly suggest